# FFMPEG api avformat_find_stream_info does not provide width and height of stream when decoders are disabled

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

We are using FFMPEG library and we have disabled decoders, demuxers using following using compile time options

```
--disable-decoders
--disable-demuxers
--enable-demuxer=mov
--enable-demuxer=matroska
--enable-demuxer=mpegts
```

After putting above options while compilation, we are not getting width and height of video stream using avformat_find_stream_info() API

we do following api sequence to get stream information

`avformat_open_input();`

then we call

`avformat_find_stream_info(format_context, nullptr);`

to get stream information, when we try to get width/height of stream we get always zero

```
format_context->streams[0]->codecpar->width always gives zero

format_context->streams[0]->codecpar->height always gives zero
```

Is there any other way to get width and height of the stream?

Answer (score 0):

avformat is used to decapsulate audio and video files or network protocols.
You haven't gotten to the decoding process yet. Decoding requires the avcodec package.

Here's how I unseal it：

```
std::string url("Apologize.mp4");
AVFormatContext *f_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();
avformat_open_input(&f_ctx, url.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr);

avformat_find_stream_info(f_ctx, nullptr);

for (int i = 0; i < f_ctx->nb_streams; ++i) {
    AVStream *stream = f_ctx->streams[i];
    AVMediaType mediaType = stream->codecpar->codec_type;
    if (mediaType == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        printf("height:%d, width:%d", stream->codecpar->height, stream->codecpar->width);
    }
}
```

It has nothing to do with this compilation. Because we haven't gotten to the decoding process yet.

```
--disable-decoders
--disable-demuxers
--enable-demuxer=mov
--enable-demuxer=matroska
--enable-demuxer=mpegts
```

format_context->streams[0] This may not be your video stream